# Why flow doesn't execute, no error thrown?

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-flow, kotlin-coroutines

Neither GlobalScope or a custom CoroutineScope instance works:

```kotlin
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.*

fun makeFlow() = flow {
    println("sending first value")
    emit(1)
    println("first value collected, sending another value")
    emit(2)
    println("second value collected, sending a third value")
    emit(3)
    println("done")
}

@InternalCoroutinesApi
fun main() {
    val someScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default)
    someScope.launch {
        makeFlow().collect { value ->
            println("value is $value")
        }
    }
    GlobalScope.launch {
        makeFlow().collect { value ->
            println("value is $value")
        }
    }
}
```

There is absolutely no output or error thrown

Why?

Even stranger, when I add a `runBlocking{}` blocks, everything executes:

```kotlin
val someScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default)
    someScope.launch {
        makeFlow().collect { value ->
            println("someScope: value is $value")
        }
    }
    GlobalScope.launch {
        makeFlow().collect { value ->
            println("GlobalScope: value is $value")
        }
    }
    runBlocking {
        makeFlow().collect { value ->
            println("runBlocking: value is $value")
        }
    }
```

Outputs:

```
sending first value
sending first value
sending first value
runBlocking: value is 1
GlobalScope: value is 1
first value collected, sending another value
GlobalScope: value is 2
second value collected, sending a third value
GlobalScope: value is 3
done
someScope: value is 1
first value collected, sending another value
someScope: value is 2
second value collected, sending a third value
someScope: value is 3
done
first value collected, sending another value
runBlocking: value is 2
second value collected, sending a third value
runBlocking: value is 3
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your launched coroutines don't get to finish because the `main` function returns right after firing them without waiting on them, thereby finishing your application. There's no error occurring because it's expected behavior.

`runBlocking`'s lambda will not return until all the coroutines within it return. In this case, it just happens to waste enough time to allow the other two coroutines time to finish, probably because it's launched last and does about the same amount of work.

If you introduce a delay to the first two, they won't have a chance to finish:

```
fun main() {
    val someScope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.Default)
    someScope.launch {
        delay(100L)
        makeFlow().collect {
            makeFlow().collect { value ->
                println("value is $value")
            }
        }
    }
    GlobalScope.launch {
        delay(100L)
        makeFlow().collect { value ->
            println("value is $value")
        }
    }
    runBlocking {
        makeFlow().collect { value ->
            println("runBlocking: value is $value")
        }
    }
}
```

```
sending first value
runBlocking: value is 1
first value collected, sending another value
runBlocking: value is 2
second value collected, sending a third value
runBlocking: value is 3
done
```