# subscribeOn(Schedulers.io()) not working but subscribeOn(Schedulers.trampoline()) does

Tags: kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

```kotlin
fun main() {
    Single.just("faefw")
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.trampoline())
        .map {
            println("map in thread ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
        }
        .flatMap {
            return@flatMap Single.just(231).map {
                println("map in thread ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
                return@map it
            }
        }
        .subscribe({
            println(it)
        }, {
            println(it)
        })
}
```

prints out:

```
map in thread main
map in thread main
231
```

But

```kotlin
fun main() {
    Single.just("faefw")
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .map {
            println("map in thread ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
        }
        .flatMap {
            return@flatMap Single.just(231).map {
                println("map in thread ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
                return@map it
            }
        }
        .subscribe({
            println(it)
        }, {
            println(it)
        })
}
```

outputs nothing!

`subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())` and `subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())` do not work either

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program is exiting before the code has time to execute. Try with a sleep or put in a print statement after subscribe

```kotlin
fun main() {
    Single.just("faefw")
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .map {
            println("map in thread ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
        }
        .flatMap {
            return@flatMap Single.just(231).map {
                println("map in thread ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
                return@map it
            }
        }
        .subscribe({
            println(it)
        }, {
            println(it)
        })
    println("just subscribed in last statement!")
    Thread.sleep(500)
    println("exiting main thread...")
}
```

with trampoline the output is

```
map in thread main
map in thread main
231
just subscribed in last statement!
exiting main thread...
```

with other schedulers which do the "work" in different threads (like `.io()` and `.computation()`) will have output like this:

```
just subscribed in last statement!
map in thread RxComputationThreadPool-1
map in thread RxComputationThreadPool-1
231
exiting main thread...
```

PS. The `io()` scheduler you can think of as unbounded thread pool, `computation()` as a bounded thread pool.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I actually asked similar questions about Kotlin Flow not long ago. Silly me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62204492/why-flow-doesnt-execute-no-error-thrown